# Need help looping for different values of tolerance for Successive over relaxation method

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following code for a Successive over-relaxation method where it gives me the no. of iterations it took to give me the answer for a certain tolerance value.

I want help in adjusting this code so that I can get the answer for different values of tolerances i.e. [10^-4, 10^-6, 10^-8, 10^-10, 10^-12]

I know I need to put a for loop outside the existing while loop but I cannot figure out how.  Can someone help me with this, please?

```
N=100;
ID = 30177207;% ENTER YOUR STUDENT ID HERE
[A,b]= set_A(ID,N);

xnew=linspace(0,0,length(A))';
n=size(xnew,1);
normVal=Inf;
nmax=1000; %number of maximum iterations which can be reached%
tol= 10^-4; % Tolerence for method%
iter=0;
omega = 1.7;

while normVal>tol && iter<nmax
    x_old=xnew;
        
    for i=1:n
        
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;

        for j=1:i-1  % sum the terms involving "new" values
            sum1 = sum1 + A(i,j)*xnew(j);
        end
        for j=i+1:n    % sum the terms involving "old" values
            sum2 = sum2 + A(i,j)*x_old(j);
        end
        
        xnew(i) = (b(i) - sum1 - sum2)/A(i,i); % new value of x(i)
        xnew = (1-omega)+ omega*xnew; %relaxation, so for omega = 1 it will give same answer as the gauss seidel method

    end
    iter=iter+1;
    normVal=norm(x_old-xnew);
end

fprintf('Solution of the system is in %d iterations',iter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code, but since you have an iterative method that runs while `normVal > tol` what you can do is to iterate over decreasing values of tol, and every time you leave the `while` loop you will have the solution within the given tolerance possibly you have the same solution for different tolerances.

```
N=100;
ID = 30177207;% ENTER YOUR STUDENT ID HERE
[A,b]= set_A(ID,N);

xnew=linspace(0,0,length(A))';
n=size(xnew,1);
normVal=Inf;
nmax=1000; %number of maximum iterations which can be reached%
tol= 10^-4; % Tolerence for method%
iter=0;
omega = 1.7;
for tol = [10^-4, 10^-6, 10^-8, 10^-10, 10^-12]
  while normVal>tol && iter<nmax
    x_old=xnew;
        
    for i=1:n
        
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;

        for j=1:i-1  % sum the terms involving "new" values
            sum1 = sum1 + A(i,j)*xnew(j);
        end
        for j=i+1:n    % sum the terms involving "old" values
            sum2 = sum2 + A(i,j)*x_old(j);
        end
        
        xnew(i) = (b(i) - sum1 - sum2)/A(i,i); % new value of x(i)
        xnew = (1-omega)+ omega*xnew; %relaxation, so for omega = 1 it will give same answer as the gauss seidel method

    end
    iter=iter+1;
    normVal=norm(x_old-xnew);
  end
  fprintf('here you have a solution for tol = %g', tol);
end
```